# My predicted value only ever decreases for gradient descent

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I am currently writing an implementation for gradient descent and I'm running into an issue where my predicted value (y_hat) only ever decreases. It never increases even though it should increase in cases where the training label is 1 and not 0. my train function code is below:

```
def sigma(self, a):
    ans = 1/(1+np.exp(-a))
    return ans

  def get_loss(self, y_i, y_hat):
    loss = -(y_i * np.log(y_hat) + (1 - y_i) * np.log(1 - y_hat))
    return loss

def train(self, X, y, step_size, num_iterations):
    b_0 = 0
    rows = X.shape[0]
    columns = X.shape[1]
    weights = np.zeros(columns)
    losses = []
    for iteration in range(num_iterations):
      #Step 1: calculate y hat for row 
      summation = 0
      summation_k = np.zeros(columns)
      total_loss = 0
      for i in range(rows):
        row_total = np.sum(np.multiply(X[i], weights))
        y_hat = self.sigma(b_0 + row_total)
        y_i = y[i]
        # print('y_i: ', y_i)
        # print('y_hat: ', y_hat)
        # print()
        total_loss += self.get_loss(y_i, y_hat)
        diff = y_i - y_hat
        summation += diff

        # summation_k_i = summation_k_i + X[i] * diff
        summation_k = np.add(summation_k, np.multiply(diff, X[i]))
        
      # Compute change for each weight based on errors, then update the weights
      # Update b_0
      b_0 = b_0 + step_size * ((1/rows) * (-summation))

      # Update b_k
      # for j in range(columns):
      #   weights[j] = weights[j] + step_size * ((1/rows) * (-summation_k[j]))
      weights = np.add(weights, np.multiply(summation_k, (-step_size/rows)))
      
      # Keeping track of average loss for each iteration.
      losses.append(total_loss/rows)
    
    self.weights = np.insert(weights, 0, b_0)
    return np.array(losses)
```

When I run this the y_hat values always decrease for every row and in every iteration. I can't find the bug that's causing this.

Comment: Isn't gradient descent about minimising the cost function where the cost function is ```1/N * np.sum(np.sqrt(y_hat - y))```? Is the error going down, that is the question ```Error = y_predicted - y_actual```.

Comment: No, the error is increasing. y_actual is either 0 or 1, and y_predicted is a number within that range. What I'm getting is a decreasing y_predicted value (it goes down to 0.000000001 and even further). Also yes we're trying to find the weights with the minimum loss. This is for a class assignment and our professor gave us a worksheet with the equations for updating the values of b_0 and the weights so I'm following those formulas.